# How to create this background with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was wondering how I can create a background like this using Adobe Illustrator ( ignore the images at the corners, I am only interested at the Orange background ).

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1):

I would normally do something like this in Photoshop but since you asked for Illustrator I'll show you an Illustrator only method...

Take some appropriate textures (either get out your camera or find some online). Choosing the right textures is very important here.

I'll start with these two:

[image]

Image trace each texture. Tweak the options until you have something like this:

[image]

Stack your textures over a solid color and change the colors appropriately:

[image]